# How to update a field value for a node?

Tags: 7, entities

I want to change the value of a field for a node.I used the following code:

```
$node = node_load($nid); // $nid is the function's parameter
$node->field['field_myfield'][$node->language][0]['value'] = 1;
node_save($node);
```

The problem is `$node->language` returns `es` while in `print_r($node)` it's `und`.
Why `$node->language` is different from what's in *$node* array and how can I get it?

Answer (score 42):

```
$node = node_load($nid);
$node_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node);
$node_wrapper->field_myfield->set(1);
$node_wrapper->save();
```

Entity metadata wrapper is a great way for set or read values of fields in the node!

Comment: I prefer entity_metadata_wrapper bc it does make things nice and clean. I would include a check for whether $node exists after the node_load() to avoid a nasty error when inadvertently passing NULL into entity_metadata_wrapper().

Comment: You can directly pass the $nid to EMW.

Comment: using entity_metadata_wrapper should be the accepted answer.

Comment: In case it's not obvious to others, entity_metadata_wrapper() is part of the Entity API module: https://www.drupal.org/project/entity

Answer (score 11):

Try `field_attach_update()` function.

```
$node = node_load($nid); // $nid is the function's parameter
$node->field['field_myfield'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = 1;
field_attach_update('node', $node);
```

It will update the field's value and it performs better than `node_save`.

Comment: why field_attach_update is downvoted?

Answer (score 6):

```
$node = node_load($nid); 
$field_language = field_language('node', $node, 'field_myfield');
$node->field['field_myfield'][$field_language][0]['value'] = 1;
node_save($node);
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to update only field value (without updating node metadata about updated time, revisions) use function `field_attach_update()`.

Example:

```
$node = node_load($nid);
$field_language = field_language('node', $node, 'field_myfield');
$node->field_fieldname[$field_language][0]['value'] = 'some value';
field_attach_update('node', $node);
```

Sometimes additionally you might need to reset node static cache with `resetCache(array($nid))`:

```
entity_get_controller('node')->resetCache(array($node->nid));
```

Source: [Saving node's fields without saving the node itself](http://www.urbaninsight.com/2011/10/24/saving-nodes-fields-without-saving-node-itself#comment-8418)

Answer (score 2):

I have just implemented this and found that this code worked for me.

```
$node = node_load($nid); 
if (isset($node)) {
  $field_language = field_language('node', $node, 'field_myfield');
  $node->field_fieldname[$field_language][0]['value'] = 'some value';
  node_save($node);
}
```

Note that I when updating field_fieldname I found that using this in line 4

```
$node->field['field_myfield'][0]['value'] = 'some value';
```

did not work.