# How to update a field in Drupal 7 without saving whole node

Tags: 7, database

I wanted to update a field that is not seen by the user, but I would turn off and on (boolean) quite a lot (and for thousands of nodes). I initially used field_attach, but this had the unhappy effect of removing a file that was also attached to the node (this is a drupal bug).

It took a lot of searching, but I found the solution combining a couple of other peoples snippets. I put it below so hopefully may save someone some time.

For the record: Apparently it is bad practice to edit fields directly like this, however, I really needed to for this use case and I have yet to find any issues. You have been warned!

Comment: See my answer here https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/99846/6309

Answer (score 2):

```
function common_update_db($entity_id, $field_name, $value, $clear_cache) {
  foreach (array('data', 'revision') as $table) {
    $result = db_update('field_'.$table.'_'.$field_name)
        ->fields(array(
            $field_name.'_value' => $value,
        ))
        ->condition('entity_id',$entity_id,'=')
        ->execute();
  }
  if ($clear_cache) {
    cache_clear_all("field:node:" . $entity_id, 'cache_field');
  }
}
```

This will update the field and the revision field. If you send clear_cache = TRUE, it will also clear that nodes cache. This only works for *_value fields and nodes, but it's easy to modify.

**Examples:**

```
common_update_db(1234, field_run_cron, 1, TRUE);
```

on node 1234, set field_run_cron value to 1 and clear the cache for immediate visible effect to the user.

```
common_update_db(1234, field_run_cron, 0, FALSE);
```

on node 1234, set field_run_cron value to 0, don't clear cache as the user doesn't see this field anyway.

Comment: Thank you - this solution worked for me. I know you're not *supposed* to update a node's field in this way, but I haven't noticed any negative effects yet and node_save() is just not an option when dealing with > 1000 nodes.