# Update a field on a node after hitting save

Tags: nodes, hooks

I am working on a Drupal 7 custom module and would like to update a field on a node after hitting save.  Based on some post that I have seen this should be [possible](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/12290/how-to-update-a-field-value-for-a-node).

As it is now I have the $node object is a parameter to the node_submit hook after hitting save.

However, I am not able to update my field on this node object.  Any pointers or examples of how to do this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks, 
Derek

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your exact usage, you'd want to use either

1) `hook_node_presave` - Called on any node being saved (inserted or updated). [see here](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_presave/7)

2) [Attach a submit handler](http://tylerfrankenstein.com/user/4/code/attach-custom-submit-handler-drupal-form) to the form: Allows to change the form's values before the submit is completed.

Comment: Amir, thanks so much for you replay. I tried the hook_node_presave approach which seems promising.  However, I am noticing that hook_node_presave seems to occur after hook_node_submit.  And I am working with some variables in hook_node_submit which I trying to use to update the field value with.

Comment: Again, usage depends on what you need. `hook_node_presave` occurs just before the node is being saved to the database, regardless of context which will allow you to globally change things, but without the form's context.

Using a submit handler will let you change the submitted values before anything else occurs - with all the values inputted in the form's field.

Comment: I like the form_alter approach and am trying that as a submit handler.  However, I am trying read the path to a file that is uploaded within this handler. This function fires before save is hit. This may really be for a different topic but do you know if it possible to get the path to a file upload within the form_alter?  Thanks.

Comment: Amir, I was able to get this working with hook_file_insert.  Thanks again for your original advice as it did point me in the right direction.